# Calling applescript from shell script using admin previleges

Tags: shell, applescript, admin

I'm running a shell script that runs an installation program (by ViseX) and selects different items in the installer through a list.
The installer needs administrator privileges to run properly, but I don't want to use sudo.
Currently the installation application does not work properly because it does not run with admin privileges.

How do I call the applescript with admin privileges or tell the installation app inside the applescript to run as admin?

Here's the applescript I'm using:

```
osascript <<-END
  tell application "$1"
    with timeout of 8 * 3600 seconds
     activate
     Select "$2"
     DoInstall
   end timeout
 end tell
END
```

Comment: And what is your question?  Does it not work?  If so, exactly how is it failing?

Answer (score 0):

You can run shell scripts from an Applescript as an admin: see [this technote](http://developer.apple.com/technotes/tn2002/tn2065.html).
So if you create this applescript as a separate script you could use it. Ugly, but should work.

Comment: So what you're saying is from my shell script I should run an applescript that runs a shell script that gives the ability to run another applescript as an admin?
Ugly indeed.

Comment: I tried using this method but I'm having problems sending variables to the applescript from the "do shell script" command.
I still prefer to use an easier way.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an applescript that does that. I'll leave you to turn it into a shell command. The following script opens the host file on your computer using TextEdit. You'll notice that admin privileges are required to open that file thus it makes for a good example. Note that I could do this particular task easier, but I'm doing it this way to show you how to launch an application with admin privileges and then target that application so you can perform other applescript commands...

```
set theFile to "/private/etc/hosts"

-- launch the application with admin privileges and get the pid of it
set thePID to (do shell script "/Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents/MacOS/TextEdit > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!" with administrator privileges) as integer

-- get the bundle identifier of that pid so we can do something with the application
delay 0.2
tell application "System Events"
    set theProcess to first process whose unix id is thePID
    set bi to bundle identifier of theProcess
end tell

-- do something with it eg. open the hosts file
set theFileAlias to (POSIX file theFile) as alias
tell application id bi
    activate
    open theFileAlias
end tell
```

Comment: This worked but I ran into some trouble.
I used this applescript to run the shell script as an external file through the terminal - I replaced the Notepad.app with Terminal.app.
Problem is that the script now runs as root. This is a problem because I use ~/ sign in my shell script (writing log files to the user's desktop f.e.).
Also, the ViseX installer which I am running from the script doesn't run well as root.

Comment: I can't comment on ViseX, but as for needing to log to the user's desktop, just get the user's name using "set userName to short user name of (get system info)" then specify the path rather than using "~". You might also have to change the file's permissions after writing the log so the user can open it.

Comment: That might work but the biggest problem is that the ViseX installer simply won't work as root. I'm pretty sure that the bug comes from ViseX (one of many) and I can't fix it myself. I'll report the bug but I hardly think they'll ever fix it.

Comment: Just like you can run something as root from a regular user account, I'm sure you can run something as a regular user from the root account. I don't have that answer offhand but it sounds like that's what you need to do as long as ViseX is required in your installation process. Your best bet would be to do away with that if possibe though.

Answer (score 0):

```
do shell script "[path/to/app] [param]" user name "[admin name]" password "[password]" with administrator privileges
```