# opening an application using a condition statement to check if another application is open or closed applescript

Tags: applescript

I've searched around the web and even on this site, but can't find an answer.
All I want to do is something simple as a test like running firefox if textedit is open.  I can open applications but I am not too good with much more.
Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: This should solve your problem: [How do I check that an application is running when I have its file path?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669876/how-do-i-check-that-an-application-is-running-when-i-have-its-file-path)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
if application "TextEdit" is running then activate application "Firefox"
```